# Why is a runtime error is produced when we return a local address but not a local variable?

Tags: c, pointers

For example:

Code snippet 1:

```
int func()
{
   int x=5; 
   return x; 
}
```

This function wouldn't produce a runtime error.

Code snippet 2:

```
char* func()
{
  char str1[]="HELLO"; 
  return str1; 
}
```

This would produce a runtime error -"Address of local variable is being returned".

Comment: In each case, a copy of the value is returned.  The difference is that the copy of `5` is still valid, but the copy of the pointer no longer points to a valid address — `str1` points to memory that is no longer valid when the function returns.

Comment: With `return str1;` you return a pointer to the first element of the array `str1`, it's equal to `return &str1[0];`. The life-time of the array `str1` ends with the end of the function, so the pointer you return is to an object that no longer exist. With `return x;` you return a copy of the value stored in `x`, but not a pointer to `x` itself.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ohh thanku!

Comment: Are you sure it produces  _runtime error_  and not a  _compilation error_?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh thanks!

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes it's a runtime error, only a warning was produced

Comment: @TonyTannous the terms "error" and "warning" are mixed up by beginners. But I really wonder how this can trigger a runtime error.

Comment: @otaku2310 what is your platform/compiler/IDE/OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int func()
{
   int x=5; 
   return x; 
}
```

Function returns an int, the **value** of x is being returned.

```
char* func()
{
  char str1[]="HELLO"; 
  return str1; 
}
```

Function returns `char*`, the **address** of `str1` is being returned. The storage duration of a local variable is limited to it's scope. Once `func()` returns, that address of `str1` is not valid hereafter. Shall you dereference that returned pointer, you will trigger undefined behavior.